# How much does a passenger-to-freighter conversion cost?

Tags: airliner, cost, cargo

Transforming a passenger airliner to a freighter seems to be [common](http://aeroacq.com/PAX-to-Cargo/). If I understand correctly (do not hesitate to correct me), it basically consists of removing many components (seats, galley, ...) as done in the first phases of a D-check, and then the handling equipment is added (as it should be done in the late phases of a D-check for freighters).

How much does the transformation cost compared to a D-check?

Related: [How much does a D-check cost compared to a new aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17596) (Useful to have an idea of D-check costs.)

Comment: #TIL: manutention. I did not know that was a word.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the cost vary considerably depending on the plane being converted?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, as D check. I expect both to vary the same way.

Comment: @FreeMan manutention is a french word. I thought it was the same in english (my bad, edited)

Comment: There is considerably more to P2F (passenger-to-freight) conversion than just stripping stuff out and inserting handling equipment. [In this photo of a newly-converted A330](https://cdn.jetphotos.com/full/6/38988_1507579009.jpg), the green primer shows where the fuselage has been reinforced; notably, an entirely new framework to take the cargo door, but also the existing frames all the way along the fuselage.

Comment: No worries, @ManuH! there was a definition for it as an English word as well. Plus, I learned a new word!

Comment: @Fiddlesticks -- why is primer showing on the outside where frames have been added?  To cover the rivet heads?  Could be the basis for another question I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Companies converted 87 passenger jets in 2018 ... Direct conversion costs for the 87 aircraft totaled \$641.5 million ... The direct cost of converting a Boeing 767-300ER amounts to some \$14 million, compared with \$15 million for an A330-200 and \$16 million for an A330-300 ...

Source: *[Freighter Conversion Market Totaled Nearly \$1B in 2018: IBA](https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/air-transport/2019-05-23/freighter-conversion-market-totaled-nearly-1b-2018-iba),* ainonline.com

2018's average is 7–8 million USD per conversion.

Based on this [source](http://aircraftmonitor.com/uploads/1/5/9/9/15993320/basics_of_aircraft_maintenance_programs_for_financiers___v1.pdf), an A330-300's heavy (D) check costs 3.8 million USD (adjusted for inflation from 2010 to 2018), and given the quoted conversion for the A333, it's ~4 times as much to do the conversion.

> [image]
>   Source: *[Boeing 747-400 Passengers to Cargo Conversion](https://youtu.be/0JeDrrOL5gk),* Israel Aerospace Industries, YouTube

Of the changes:

- The fuselage is cut and reinforced to allow for the bigger door
- The floor may require reinforcement
- Passenger environmental control systems are removed
- Cargo fire suppression is installed
- A [9G crash net](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/60913/14897) is installed.

More in this [A330-300/-200 P2F brochure](https://www.elbeflugzeugwerke.com/fileadmin/pdfs/EFW_T_A330-300_200_P2F_web.pdf) (PDF). And then there is certification.